# Any tips on how to fight the Thunderjaw?

Tags: horizon-call-of-the-mountain

In Horizon Call of the Mountain you fight a Thunderjaw at some point. I'm having some difficulties with this fight and so far didn't succeed. The fight also takes quite a bit of time which does get tiring when you're actually waving your arms around pretending to fire arrows.

The amount of special arrows I have is pretty limited, I can set it on fire once and shock it once. As far as I can tell I can't really craft more and I can't craft while in the fight. So most of the time I fire basic arrows into it, which hardly do damage unless I manage to detach a component.

Evading his attacks is also not always easy, I think I'm missing some dodge mechanics here as well. I use the square+X and wave both arms in one direction dodge. Which I have to do several times in a row for most attacks. Is there anything else I can do here to evade those attacks?

And where should I use my precious tear arrows? I'm not sure my knowledge from the main games carries over here well.

Any other tips for this fight?